# SQL Server concat and convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, concatenation, scientific-notation

In SQL Server I am using the `concat` function to join two columns. One column is numeric. Because of that after `concat`, the output shows that number in scientific notation. Is there any way to avoid that scientific notation?

I tried

```
concat (convert (numbercolumn as varachar), text_column)
```

but I get an error

> concat is not a recognized built in function name

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: *"the output shows that number in scientific notation"* This implies your source column is a `float`/`real` which is a problem unto itself.

Comment: `CONCAT` was added in SQL Server in SQL Server 2008. If you are getting the message *"concat is not a recognized built in function name."* then you are using a version that is end of life and you really need to get that upgrade sorted out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't need to explicitly convert, so:

```
concat(numbercolumn, textcolumn)
```

If this still converts to exponential, then convert to a *decimal* first.  I'm not sure what you want things to look like but something like:

```
concat(convert(decimal(38, 10), numbercolumn), textcolumn)
```

You can also use `format()` or `str()` to convert the value to a string.